# C# While Loops - TicTacToe, conditions in while loop are met but not executed

Tags: c#, while-loop

I made a simple tic-tac-toe game and this `while` loop will not break.

I made 1 function, 1 variable that either can be `true` to stop the loop.

Within the function, all indexes of the `string[]` board array is purposely arranged when it is declared to have a whitespace so it can work with its conditions with `AllArrFilledEmptySpace();`

Here is the code:

[image: C# code in an editor]

Here is the second:

[image: C# code in an editor]

Comment: Please describe in more detail what is happening and how that deviates from your expecations.

Comment: Sounds like a good time to break out the debugger and step through the executing code

Comment: Also note that the correct/acceptable way to include code in your question is to copy/paste the code (as text) into your question and format it as code.  Pictures of text really don't work here.  A tic-tac-toe board modeled as a single dimension array is also unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked the question twice, I'll answer it twice...

If the game is not ended (`!gameEnd`) then `AllArrFilledEmptySpace(board)` will not be called because there is a or (`||`) between them.

And when `AllArrFilledEmptySpace()` is not called `gameEnd` will never be set to `true` and `AllArrFilledEmptySpace()` will never be called.